# Istio ingress pod is re-creating after installation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, azure-aks, istio-kiali

I have installed istio 1.6.7 in an AKS cluster using `istioctl`.
I have enabled the istio operator using `init` command.
When I try to enable Grafana and Kiali using a separate yaml on top of the installed istio system with `kubectl`, the istio ingress gateway pod is recreated and my custom configurations are deleted.

The documentation specifies that we can install add-ons with `kubectl`.

Add-on yaml is as follows:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  values:
   grafana:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are referring to the [Standalone Operator Installation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/standalone-operator/) guide. When updating the configuration, you have to change the original manifest and not create a new one. Your specified manifest doesn't contain any profile or metadata information. It should look like the following:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: default
  addonComponents:
    grafana:
      enabled: true
```